# Delete objects in Realm List

Tags: ios, swift, realm

How do you properly delete objects in a realm list? Is this the proper way:

```
class Parent: Object {
    dynamic var children: List<Child>
}


realm.write {
        realm.delete(parent.children)
        parent.childList.removeAll()
    }
```

My tests are not liking this

Comment: I think it should be something like `realm.delete(parent.children)`. Here's delete documentation: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm6deleteFS0_FCS_6ObjectT_

Comment: When you say "My tests are not liking this", what's going wrong? The code you shared should work

Comment: "My tests are not liking this" is so generic, what the error you got? Did you find a solution for your case?